# Counting no of records from the files using Bash script

Tags: bash, awk

I have written this script to count the no of records that are present in the files on the AWS s3 location.

```
#!/bin/bash

export bucket="$1"
export prefix="$2"
export threads="$3"

copy_and_count(){
  temp_file=$(mktemp)
  aws s3 cp "s3://$bucket/$1" "$temp_file"
  line_count=$(sed -n '$=' "$temp_file")
  echo $line_count
  rm "$temp_file"
}

main(){
  objects=$(aws s3 ls "s3://$bucket/$prefix" --recursive | awk '{print $4}')
  echo "$objects" | xargs -n 1 -P "$threads" -I {} bash -c 'copy_and_count "{}"' | awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}' > total_count.txt
}

export -f copy_and_count

main
```

This script works for smaller data sets like 4 or 5 files having 10000 records in the file,
but when I am running the same script for a larger data set like 5000 files having the same records in each file then I am not getting the correct count

Here is the command that I am using to run the file

```
bash script.sh bucket-name object-prefix 10
```

Here I am using dummy values for the bucket-name and object-prefix and 10 is the number of parallel threads that I am invoking

So I am not sure why this is happening, whether it is due to parallel threads or something else is going on here.

Comment: Why not use `wc -l`, that's what it's for?

Comment: There's no need for the temp file. Use `-` as the filename in `aws s3 cp` and it will write to stdout, then you can pipe to the command that counts lines.

Comment: wc -l counts the lines \n delimited but if your last line doesn't have \n then that line doesn't count so that why I have used sed -n '$='

Comment: If the last line doesn't end in `\n` than it's not a valid text file per POSIX and then you can't rely on sed or any other text processing tool handling it as you want either. Why don't your files end with `\n` and can you fix whatever is creating them?

Comment: If you think parallel threads might be the problem then run it single threaded to see if you still have the problem or not.

Comment: Assuming that `aws s3 ls` has the same behavior as regular `ls` then see https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs.

Comment: `awk '{s+=$1} END {print s}'` will output a blank line for an empty input file when you probably want `0` instead - do `awk '{s+=$1} END {print s+0}'` to solve that problem.

Comment: Okay, But I can see when I am running the wc -l for the file I am getting one less count lets support there are 100 UUIDs in the file then I am getting 99 but with the sed -n '$=' I am getting 100 as a count, so that was the reason behind using that.

Comment: Will change the awk as you suggested, also to run it sequentially the data is very huge so it is taking a lot of time.

Comment: Are there any filenames with spaces in their names? `$objects` won't work correctly. It's basically the same problem as https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls

Comment: I understand that with the version of the sed variant you ran you got the count you wanted but it's **undefined behavior** and so you may get different results  with other sed variants or other versions of your current one and/or other tools you want to run on the files and so a better solution would be to fix the files that have the problem by fixing whatever's creating them to always provide the terminating `\n` required for a valid POSIX text file.

Comment: Regrading "to run it sequentially the data is very huge so it is taking a lot of time." - I'm not saying that's the permanent solution to your problem, I'm saying do it one time to find out if the issue is parallelism or not so you can focus on fixing that parallelism problem or move on to investigating what else might be the problem.